# How to manage combinations of styles: multiple classes, specific classes, or context?

Tags: naming-conventions, css-selectors, css

I'm not much of a web designer or programmer, but I seem to run into this issue with CSS classes: what's the best way of managing sets of CSS classes that share attributes in common?

For example, I'm currently working on an application with a status bar representing the status of a file transfer. It's used in three different locations, each of which is a different size.   In addition, if the transfer fails, the bar should be a different color.

What's the best approach, in general:

1. Add "statusbar" and "transfer-failed" classes to the divs independently, and check for their combined existence?
2. Have "statusbar" and "statusbar-failed" classes, set the class appropriately, and use careful CSS structuring to avoid repeating code.
3. Have a "statusbar" class, then use context like the div being inside a "summary" table or a "transfer-failed" div to further specialise it.

Are there any general rules? Approach 3 seems fragile, because changing the name of a seemingly unrelated class could break stuff. Approach 1 feels strange somehow, having classes like "failed" that would be meaningless without another class, and could also mean different things in different contexts (eg, "failed" could also be applied to a failed form validation...) Approach 2 sometimes gets unwieldy, with lots of very specific classes with long names.

Comment: Contextual selectors are [second nature in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#contextual-selectors). You use them every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If there will always be only one "status bar" feel free to use an
   `id` instead of a `class` for it.
2. If there will be multiple on the same page, and they look
   **anything** alike, stick with `class`.
3. Assign a `transfer-failed` class when appropriate. In in your CSS,
   under this class, should only have the properties that
   differentiates it of the default "status bar". Personally, I like #3
   (the context approach). [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) and other CSMs assign the page
   name and category (and anything else you'd like) as `<body>`
   classes. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) uses the `<html>` tag. More info here: http://perishablepress.com/dynamic-body-class-id-php-wordpress/
4. **@Lokase**'s SMACSS is great. For more tips on organizing your CSS, check this out: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/10/70-expert-ideas-for-better-css-coding/

Comment: Somehow ended up on this one too: http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Take some time to look at a few CSS methodologies or frameworks, I am a fan of [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/)

There are a lot examples of best practices out there, you just have to find them and go through the learning curve.

Comment: ...and then try and persuade the other members of the project. :)

Comment: Best practices are easily defended in a team environment.  Its the managers that put up the most huff.

Comment: yeah, but distributed open source teams that are also working on other things are harder. (I'm not saying I won't try...)